# two views ontouchlistener same area how to?

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I have a two ImageViews.

1.ImageView zoomImageMoveable : should zoom in,out and moveable. 
2.ImageView zoomImageFixed : show zoom this is guide line.

I want run different functions from one touch.

```
{
 FrameLayout myFrame = new FrameLayout(this.getContext());
     myFrame.addView(zoomImageMoveable);
     myFrame.addView(zoomImageFixed);
}
```

Case 1. I tried to attach a listener to each of the view, as they are overlapping only one works.

Case 2. I also tried to wrap the two view with a FrameLayout and added an  OnTouchListener to that layout to have it forward the calls to each of the assigned methods. Yet this method also didn't work.

```
 myFrame.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           zoomImageMoveable.onTouchEvent(event);
           zoomImageFixed.onTouchEvent(event);
           return false;
      }
 });
```

How should I approach this issue?